# Android Rendering: traversal takes long time and main thread is paused

Tags: android, graphics, gpu, rendering

I am doing performance analysis of the animation because it does not reach 60 fps, with each animation frame taking quite a broad range from 15 to 40 ms and I am trying to understand where the time is spent. The app does not have a lot of stuff. I have recorded a systrace and I see that choreographer step takes relatively long (example on the picture was 30 ms) but it looks like it not really doing anything since thread is not running.

Any hints on what happening here? Is it like, normal?

[image: Systrace]